# Weird output with varargs in C

Tags: c, variadic-functions

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
void f(int parameter, ...)
{
    va_list ap; 
    int j;
    va_start(ap, parameter); 
    for (j = parameter; j >= 0; j = va_arg(ap, int))
        printf("%d ", j); 
    va_end(ap);
    printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
    f(1, 2, 3, 4); 
    f(1, 2);
    f(1);
}
```

I write this code, but the output is very strange.Who can tell me the reason.
the output:

```
esekilvxen245 [10:54am] [/home/elqstux/useful] -> ./a.out
1 2 3 4 1748292352 1748370624 
1 2 1748295184 1745597392 
1 10 1748295184 1745597392
```

Answer (score 2):

Your ending condition for the loop is for `j` to be less than zero, but you don't end the argument list with a negative number in your calls. This means that the loop will continue until it finds a negative number, which can be anywhere on the stack far beyond the arguments you pass.

Call it like e.g.

```
f(1, 2, 3, 4, -1);
```

Comment: You are right. I am confused how to check the end?  i just use `-1`, but this is not a good method.

Comment: @BlackMamba There is no way to find an end, except having either a special value as the end-marker, or passing in the count as first argument, or using format strings like e.g. `printf`.

Comment: The first parameter can be used to count the total number of parameter, good idea.